# Missing platform-specific plugins in new RCP app

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, p2, target-platform

If I use **New -> Eclipse 4 Application Project**, and look into my `.product` file, there's this

[image]

Right. So I know I'm using Eclipse 4.5.1 RCP for Windows x64, but if I configure my target platform so that it points to the Eclipse update sites, I still get the same result.

Mind you that there's no delta pack since 4.5.x! All platform-specific plugins should be in the target platform's update sites.

[image]

Am I not including the correct features in the target platform?

[Related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258706/eclipse-rcp-e4-tycho-maven-separate-target-platform)

Comment: Where ever that plugin list came from it is out of date. The Mac OSX plugins shown as errors no longer exist and I think that applies to the others shown as errors as well.

Comment: @greg-449 Well this is silly, because these are provided by the latest 4.5.1 version from the official website. "Eclipse Mars for RCP and RAP developers". Any follow-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin list used by this Wizard is out of date. For example the Mac OSX plugins shown as errors no longer exist and I think that applies to the others shown as errors as well.

The 'New > Eclipse 4 Application Project' wizard is being removed altogether in Eclipse 4.6 [bug 473575](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473575)

Instead of this wizard use 'New > Plug-in Development > Plug-in Project'. Check the 'This project will make contributions to the UI' option and 'Yes' for 'would you like to create a rich client application'. On the templates page choose 'Eclipse 4 RCP application'